# Typescript + Angular 2: How can I ensure emitted decorator metadata will refer to variables in scope, in order to avoid "not defined" error?

Tags: angular, typescript, cross-browser, decorator

I ran into a crash in my web app on Safari because the type definition for a function referred to the `TouchEvent` interface. That variable was emitted verbatim in decorator metadata in the compiled JS, and [is not implemented in desktop Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch).

This particular instance was easy to solve (I just used `Event` instead) but it left me wondering... are there any other decorator metadata out there in my app breaking on some browsers I haven't tested?

Here's an example Angular 2 directive that illustrates the problem:

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[touchTest]'
})
export class TouchTest {
    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('touchend', ['$event']) onTouchend(event: TouchEvent) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

If you compile this with `tsc touch-test.ts --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators`, the output includes (full JS output [here](https://gist.github.com/tobek/90c133c34ddef49f8308d66ffded84ab)) this:

```
__decorate([
    core_1.HostListener('touchend', ['$event']),
    __metadata("design:type", Function),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [TouchEvent]),
    __metadata("design:returntype", void 0)
], TouchTest.prototype, "onTouchend");
```

That reference to `TouchEvent` throws `TouchEvent is not defined` on Safari.

I've noticed that some other parameter types (ones that I've explicitly imported?) are emitted simply as `Object` in the resulting JS, which is guaranteed to be safe. I also see that `interface TouchEvent` is defined in several `.d.ts` files in the `typescript` npm module, so I was able to use it without raising in errors at compile time.

Is there a general rule for avoiding problems like this? There could be some problematic setting in my environment (I started with [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)) but looking through `tsconfig.json` and other possibly-relevant config files, nothing jumped out at me.

Answer (score 1):

The `lib.d.ts` files just use the latest webspec and care little about older and lacking browsers. And they shouldn't. It's up to you to check if a built-in class/object is available in browsers you want to give support to. If it's not, you can either use polyfills or find another way around it, or drop support for these browsers (I suggest the latter :) no need to dwell in the past, or support browsers who refuse to comply with the latest standards)

Comment: Alas, this isn't about older browsers! [Neither latest Edge nor latest desktop Safari support this at all](http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch), so my app would break for too many users. I guess I have no choice but to manually inspect all of the presumably-global interfaces used in type annotations in my app, and confirm that they're actually well supported. That's a big pain.

Comment: That's what i meant with browsers who refuse to comply. Safari is one of those, just like opera

Comment: Sure, and I'm lately more and more disappointed with Safari here, but not supporting any users that use Edge or Safari is not a practical solution in most cases. What if I were working on a bank or government website? Ideally TypeScript could help out here instead of going silent on possible runtime errors. I've asked a more direct question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916890/is-there-a-more-cross-browser-safe-version-of-lib-dom-d-ts-and-other-default-amb

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/).

Comment: This isn't about using touch events, that just happened to be what surfaced the problem in this case. The problem is typescript outputting references to global variables that have no guarantee to be defined.